# How to hide and show Textview using Ternary operator

Tags: java, android, dart

I have to used Ternary operator while hiding and showing my Textview. In Dart we just used like that

```
 bool isContactInfoClicked;
 isContactInfoClicked ? contactEditInfo() : contactInfo();
```

but in java as Ternary operator return a value so what would be return type in this case

```
 boolValue ? mTextViewFitGuide.setVisibility(View.GONE) : mTextViewFitGuide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So how we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mTextViewFitGuide.setVisibility(boolValue ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

The *conditional operator* yields an expression, and is not an expression statement, so you can't use it in the way you were trying to.

Instead, use the conditional operator to pick the expression value which differs between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Put tenary expression inside the method:

```
 mTextViewFitGuide.setVisibility(boolValue ? View.GONE :View.VISIBLE);
```

Also follow DRY principal of not repeating `mTextViewFitGuide.setVisibility`